# Find the maximal and minimal values of the function f(x,y)

Tags: maxima-minima

Find the maximal and minimal values of the function f given by:
$$f(x,y) = 2x^2+y^2-4y-4x+1$$
on the triangle bounded by the lines $x = 0,y = 2x, y = 2$

Here is my work:
$$f_x =4x-4=0 => x=1$$
$$f_y =2x-4=0 => y=2$$

It appears that (1,2) is not inside the triangle. How could I use that information to evaluate f(x,y)? Thanks.

Comment: Then you know the optima must lie on the boundaries of the triangle. Directly inspect how the function behaves on each side of the triangle to find the maxima and minima.

Comment: The function is convex, so the $\max$ must occur on the boundary.

Comment: You could scale & translate the problem so that it is a nearest point problem.

Comment: So I got f(-1,-2)=19, f(0,0)=1, f(0,-2)=13. The maximum is 13 and the minimum is 1. Is that correct?